# RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults

Tags: web3js, truffle, ganache

I get the error below while calling a `view` function in my Solidity code:

```
Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0x0d7143b5df61565c7a06db77daab13716a92fb9d48b030fb45d3e3ede35e4e57": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 261,
      "return": "0x"
    },
    "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:568:26",
    "name": "RuntimeError"
  }
}
```

The client-side calling this code uses a local Ganache CLI server, Web3.js and Truffle. The weird thing about this issue is that this error occurs only when I am calling a public `view` function and DOES NOT happen when accessing the value of a state variable. To illustrate:

Here is a snippet of the Solidity code:

```
contract Contract {
    mapping (address => CreatorProfile) public creatorProfiles;

    // more smart contract code

    function getAllJobsCreated() public view returns(JobOffer[] memory) {
        return jobOffers;
    }

    // rest of smart contract
}
```

And then my NextJS + Web3.js client-side code:

```js
  const fetchedProfile: CreatorProfile = await contractInstance.methods.creatorProfiles(address).call(); // this works
  const jobOffers = await contractInstance.methods.getAllJobsCreated().call(); // this throws the error
```

This setup works on my local machine perfectly. No errors are thrown. But this does not work in the code editor widget of a platform with which I am working on a project.